# Cytoscape.js Getting IDs For All Nodes Selected

Tags: cytoscape.js

I'm using Cytoscape.js to represent a network diagram. I can highlight more than one node at a time by selecting the first node followed by the second node while holding the shift key.

How can I have all the node ids that I have selected available in Javascript? For example and this would be ideal, if all the node ids that have simultaneously selected where organized into a Javascript list.

I looked in the cytoscape.js docs and could not find the location where this is described.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To receive ids of all selected:

- elements
  `var typeIds = cy.elements(':selected');`
- nodes
  `var typeIds = cy.elements('node:selected');`
- edges
  `var ConnIds = cy.elements('edge:selected');`

In order to get Ids of all selected nodes you could try this:

```js
cy = window.cy = cytoscape ({ 
             container : document.getElementBy('cy'),
             // define a style for selected node
             style : cytoscape.stylesheet()
                     .selector('node')
                     .css ({..............})
                     .selector('edge')
                     .css({...............})
                     .selector('node:selected')
                     .css({ 'border-color' : 'red'})
                     }),
               elements : eles,
               layout : {.............}
               });
```

Comment: FYI this doesn't necessarily return the elements in the order they were selected.

Answer (score 0):

## step by step

first we need to select the elements we're interested in (eg like in Alsam's answer)

```
const typeIds = cy.elements(':selected');
```

to actually receive the ids of the collection, the ids need to be reduced from the collection.
as the id sits in `data`, we need to receive `data` for the whole collection.

```
// plural: jsons
const alldata = cy.elements(':selected').jsons();
```

then we can reduce:

```
const ids = alldata.reduce((acc,obj) => [...acc, obj.data.id], [])
```

## all in one line:

```
const ids = cy.elements(':selected').jsons().reduce((acc,obj) => [...acc, obj.data.id], [])
```